# How to render an arbitrary number of tabs in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I need to create tabs on a Shiny app, but the number of tabs depends on the result of another process, i.e., I don't know beforehand how many tabs there will be, neither their names or contents. How to create an arbitrary number of tabs based on a vector or reactive object in Shiny?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a reproducible example of a Shiny app in which tabs are produced based on a reactive object. This object can be the result of any previous computation inside your shiny app, but in this example it is merely the selected elements of a picker input. This allows for the tabs to be added/removed as soon as the reactive object changes.

```
library(shiny)
library(purrr)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(12,
           h1("Testing dynamic tabs"),
           p("Below are an arbitraty number of tabs generated from a reactive object"),
           
           pickerInput("elements", label = "Choose animals",
                       multiple = TRUE,
                       choices = NULL),
           
           #empty tabset panel that will be populated with tabs based on the previous selector
           tabsetPanel(id = "tabs")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #list of elements to choose from
  all_animals <- reactive(c("Cats", "Dogs", "Rat", "Raccoon", "Fish", "Snakes", "Capybara"))
  
  #update selector with elements
  updatePickerInput(session, "elements",
                    choices = c("Cats", "Dogs", "Rat", "Raccoon", "Fish", "Snakes", "Capybara"), 
                    selected = c("Cats", "Raccoon", "Capybara")
  )
  
  #reactive objetct, in this example, just the contents of the picker input
  tab_elements <- reactive({input$elements})
  
  #on input change,
  observeEvent(tab_elements(), {
    #initialize tabsetPanel (remove all tabs)
    walk(all_animals(), ~{
      removeTab("tabs", target = .x) 
    })
    
    #and then produce tabs for the selected elements
    walk(tab_elements(), ~{ #for each of the elements in the reactive object...
      insertTab("tabs", #create a tab...
                tabPanel(title = .x, #titled with the name of the element
                         #contents of each tab
                         h2(.x),
                         p("About", paste0(.x, "!")),
                         p("...further contents of the tab")
                )
      )
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```